# Close the Firefox application (alt + F4 or close button)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, exit, observer-pattern, dom-events

I would like to know when a user is about to close the Firefox application (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or close button). I have tried `onbeforeunload`, it works but only when the user presses File>>exit. I have written an observer, and used the quit-application event to know when a user quits but no event is being fired!

```
var ObserverTest = {

        register: function() {
            var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
          //  observerService.addObserver(ObserverTest, "user-interaction-active", false);
            observerService.addObserver(ObserverTest, "quit-application",false);
        },

        observe: function(subject, topic, data) {


            switch (topic) {
                case 'sessionstore-windows-restored':
                    // do stuff
                    break;
                case 'user-interaction-inactive':
                    // do stuff
                      var url = "http://localhost:13000";
                     var params = "q=hello";
                    var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
                    req.open('POST', url, true);
                    req.send('your=data&and=more&stuff=here');
                    break;
                case 'user-interaction-active':
                    // every 5 seconds and immediately when user becomes active


                    break;
                case 'quit-application':
                 obs.removeObserver(this, "quit-application");

                  alert('hello');
                  break;
                  case 'quit-application-requested':
                  alert("hello");
                  break;

            }
        },

        unregister: function() {
            var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
         //   observerService.removeObserver(ObserverTest, "user-interaction-active");
            observerService.removeObserver(ObserverText,"quit-application");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because of an error in your case statement:

```
                case 'quit-application':
                 obs.removeObserver(this, "quit-application");

                  alert('hello');
                  break;
                  case 'quit-application-requested':
                  alert("hello");
                  break;
```

Where is "obs" defined?